# LiveSassCompiler - ExcludeList issue

Tags: sass

I use Live Sass Compiler, and when i save a file, LSC compile ALL my SCSS of all my project... grrr...

My JSON :

```
{
"git.ignoreMissingGitWarning": true,
"workspace-manager.includeGlobPattern": [
    "D:\\_CLIENTS\\_WORKPLACE\\"
],

"liveSassCompile.settings.formats":[
   {
        "format": "compressed",
        "extensionName": ".min.css",
        "savePath": null
   },
],
"liveSassCompile.settings.excludeList": [
  "**/node_modules/**",
  ".vscode/**",
  "/vendor/",
  "/admin/",
],
"liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": false,
"editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
"[less]": {},

}
```

I add folders /vendor/ and /admin/ in this excludeList, but it doesn't care :( When i save a file :

```
Generated :
d:\_CLIENTS\Yoji Su\www\YojiSu\admin\assets\vendor\chartist\scss\chartist.min.css
--------------------
Generated :
d:\_CLIENTS\Yoji Su\www\YojiSu\admin\assets\vendor\trumbowyg\ui\sass\trumbowyg.min.css
--------------------
Generated :
d:\_CLIENTS\Yoji Su\www\YojiSu\admin\custom\panneau_commande.min.css
--------------------
Generated :
d:\_CLIENTS\Yoji Su\www\YojiSu\admin\custom\print.min.css
--------------------
Generated :
d:\_CLIENTS\Yoji Su\www\YojiSu\content\sass\styles.min.css
--------------------
Generated :
d:\_CLIENTS\Yoji Su\www\YojiSu\vendor\slick\slick-theme.min.css
```

etc etc...

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I first started. What worked was to created the files I didn't want compiled as Partials, (add an underscore before the name in your SCSS files that you don't want compiled.)

eg. **navBar.scss** to **_navBar.css**

This is a sample of what I mean :

[image]

Just to be clear, you should use **@use** to import the partial files to your main folder as opposed to **@import** as this is being deprecated

Check the documentation [here](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-4) for more info.